# HTTP CODE: 100 thrown but its not mapped (invoking api-rest JAVA)

Tags: java, rest, http, jboss, http-headers

I am invoking a API-REST service written in JAVA but for some odd reason it "sometimes" throws an HTTP CODE that is not mapped so i dont understand where the problem is located.

If i run the same request but in POSTMAN i always get the desired http code but if i invoke that from an application it will fail sometimes.

This is my code written in JAVA:

```
@Component
public class FessCalculator implements Processor {
    private static Map<String, Object> headers;
    private static int responseStatusCode = 200;

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String message = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("exception.message");
        String supplierName = exchange.getProperty("supplierName",String.class);
        Map<String, companyFess> output = new HashMap<>();
        companyFess companyFess = new companyFess();
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(message)) {
            Map<String, Object> map = exchange.getIn().getBody(Map.class);
            String ebsResult = (String) map.get("x_msg_data");
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(ebsResult)) {
                companyFess.setFees((List<TaxLineOut>) map.get("lines_tab"));
                output.put(supplierName, companyFess);
            } else {
                /*  API executed with errors. Fees will be empty  */
                companyFess.setMessage(ebsResult);
                companyFess.setFees(new ArrayList<TaxLineOut>());
                output.put(supplierName, companyFess);
            }
        } else {
            /* API could not be executed. Fees will be null */
            companyFess.setMessage("API Could not
 be executed");
            companyFess.setFees(new ArrayList<TaxLineOut>());
            output.put(supplierName, companyFess);
        }
        companyFessResponse response = new companyFessResponse();
        if (output == null || output.isEmpty()) {
            responseStatusCode = 400;
        } else {
            response.setCompanyFees(output);
            for (companyFess companyFess1 : output.values()) {
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(companyFess1.getMessage())) {
                    response.setStatus(500);
                }
            }
        }
        exchange.getOut().setBody(response);
        headers = exchange.getIn().getHeaders();
        headers.put(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, responseStatusCode);
        exchange.getOut().setHeaders(headers);
    }
}
```

The error shown in the application that is invoking is this:

> 8444-[2023-02-02 19:44:17] feesCalculator.CRITICAL: "feesCalculator API Exception: \"{\\n  \\\"status\\\" : 200,\\n  \\\"companyTaxes\\\" : {\\n    \\\"Company\\\" : {\\n      \\\"message\\\" : \\\"\\\",\\n      \\\"taxes\\\" : [ {\\n        \\\"tax_regime_code\\\" : \\\"USA-VAT\\\",\\n        \\\"tax\\\" : \\\"STATE\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_id\\\" : 12500,\\n        \\\"tax_rate_code\\\" : \\\"STATE NGRP 13M\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_name\\\" : \\\"VAT RAT BSAS\\\",\\n        \\\"operand\\\" : 1.1,\\n        \\\"amount\\\" : 11499.92\\n      }, {\\n        \\\"tax_regime_code\\\" : \\\"USA-VAT\\\",\\n        \\\"tax\\\" : \\\"USCF\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_id\\\" : 13779,\\n        \\\"tax_rate_code\\\" : \\\"GRP07_IIBB_CF\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_name\\\" : \\\"VAT RAT USA Res 364 AGIP 1%\\\",\\n        \\\"operand\\\" : 1,\\n        \\\"amount\\\" : 10454.49\\n      }, {\\n        \\\"tax_regime_code\\\" : \\\"USA-VAT\\\",\\n        \\\"tax\\\" : \\\"USMI\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_id\\\" : 13881,\\n        \\\"tax_rate_code\\\" : \\\"USMI CONV\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_name\\\" : \\\"VAT RAT USA\\\",\\n        \\\"operand\\\" : 3.31,\\n        \\\"amount\\\" : 0\\n      }, {\\n        \\\"tax_regime_code\\\" : \\\"USA-VAT\\\",\\n        \\\"tax\\\" : \\\"USA-VAT\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_id\\\" : 13710,\\n        \\\"tax_rate_code\\\" : \\\"USA-VAT CM 2,5\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_name\\\" : \\\"VAT RAT Tucum\\\",\\n        \\\"operand\\\" : 2.5,\\n        \\\"amount\\\" : 501.81\\n      }, {\\n        \\\"tax_regime_code\\\" : \\\"USA-VAT\\\",\\n        \\\"tax\\\" : \\\"USFO\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_id\\\" : 12035,\\n        \\\"tax_rate_code\\\" : \\\"USFO CONV\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_name\\\" : \\\"VAT RAT Formos\\\",\\n        \\\"operand\\\" : 1,\\n        \\\"amount\\\" : 0\\n      }, {\\n        \\\"tax_regime_code\\\" : \\\"USA-VAT\\\",\\n        \\\"tax\\\" : \\\"VAT\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_id\\\" : 11756,\\n        \\\"tax_rate_code\\\" : \\\"VAT 21% PP BA\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_name\\\" : \\\"VAT 21%\\\",\\n        \\\"operand\\\" : 21,\\n        \\\"amount\\\" : 47326\\n      }, {\\n        \\\"tax_regime_code\\\" : \\\"USA-VAT\\\",\\n        \\\"tax\\\" : \\\"USER\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_id\\\" : 12200,\\n        \\\"tax_rate_code\\\" : \\\"USER 3%\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_name\\\" : \\\"VAT Washington\\\",\\n        \\\"operand\\\" : 3,\\n        \\\"amount\\\" : 0\\n      }, {\\n        \\\"tax_regime_code\\\" : \\\"USA-VAT\\\",\\n        \\\"tax\\\" : \\\"VAT\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_id\\\" : 11765,\\n        \\\"tax_rate_code\\\" : \\\"VAT 21% RVTA\\\",\\n        \\\"tax_rate_name\\\" : \\\"VAT 21%\\\",\\n        \\\"operand\\\" : 21,\\n        \\\"amount\\\" : 172218.1\\n      } ]\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\"" [] []}

So, it calls the processor feesCalculator that will calculate all the different fees but for some reason it throws an http code 100 and the response is loaded.

What am i doing wrong? Am i missing anything?

I would expect to obtain only the mapped http codes

Comment: Note sure if they are the cause of your problem, but: using modifiable fields in your components is definitely a source of trouble. Imagine two clients requesting services of your component at the same time: they will overwrite each others state. Remove those two `private static ...` fields and declare them as local variables in the `process()` method.

Comment: Hey @ThomasKläger thanks for replying!
Gonna give it a try :)

Comment: I did what you told me to do but it did not solved my problem :/

Comment: @ThomasKläger it did not worked :(

Comment: I never promised that it will solve your actual problem - it merely stated that this will cause additional problems.

Comment: I wonder where you find that status 100 - your code doesn't produce it and the exception message from the client also doesn't include it. Are you searching in the correct place?

Comment: Hey @ThomasKläger yeah, i know that. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75585827/service-returning-200-in-postman-but-http-100-code-when-invoking-the-service-dir

Comment: @ThomasKläger when i invoke the same service but in POSTMAN i get a HTTP CODE = 200. The problem comes when i invoke that from the PHP application.

Comment: If you always get http code 200 when invoking the same service with PostMan but get some other result when invoking from a PHP application then maybe the problem is the PHP application.